# IP filter on .cap file

Tags: filter, ip, wireshark, tcpdump, tshark

how to apply filter on an existing .cap file ? so i have a .cap file and want to filter out one particular IP , what is the command for that . I am using wireshark .

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this sort of question an ideal candidate for Google.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ip.addr == 127.15.16.13

Sometimes you may need ip.src == ..... or ip.dst == ...

After that you may save filtered packets by selecting File->Save As->Packet Range->Displayed

Comment: I am using tshark so how will it work in accordance with that , I do not have GUI access .

Comment: According to (http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) you should use `tshark -r your_file_name -R ip.addr==127.15.16.13`

Comment: one more question , can we filter on multiple IPs ?

Comment: just add logical OR operator `||` and try to put your filter in quotes `tshark -r your_file_name -R "ip.addr==213.148.12.65||ip.src==211.33
.14.158"`