# ip filter for multiple IPs

Tags: networking, filter, ip, wireshark, tcpdump

I want to filter IPs on a .cap file , I use the command ip.addr == 123.456.789 but this only filters out one IP , I was wondering if there was a way to filter out multiple IPs ? 
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [IP filter on .cap file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671742/ip-filter-on-cap-file)

Comment: ??? didnt quite get that

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
tshark -i em0 host 10.25.100.2 or host 10.25.100.3
```

Comment: i tried that , it didnt work . The correct way to do it is  ip.addr==x.x.x.x || ip.addr==y.y.y.y || ip.addr=z.z.z.z
just got it to work after i posted my question .

Comment: I use it for 5 years in my project. Yours is Display Filter while mine example is capture filter.